# looping vectors with objects

Tags: c++, loops, vector

so what am trying to do is make a multiple objects using vector. Now my program works fine if i dont use vector and if i have only one object. so how can i have my BoxOfProduce class have more then once object using vectors. i tried what ur seeing infront of u and it works but the program then crashes and says not responding. i know i have to use the push back thing somewhere but have no idea where. i only posted the main function so you dont have to see the whole program because its too big.

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int size;


    vector<BoxOfProduce>box;
    cout<<"How many boxes you want";
    cin>>size;

    for ( x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        box[x].setItemAry();
        box[x].randomPick();


        box[x].display();
        box[x].change();
        box[x].display2();
    }

    //BoxOfProduce box;


    //box.setItemAry();
    //box.randomPick();


    //box.display();
    //box.change();
    //box.display2();



    getchar();getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a vector? If the number of items never changes after the user enters the size, it would be simpler to say BoxOfProduce box[] = new BoxOfProduce[size];

Comment: @AustinMullins This is exactly the situation where one should use a vector. It would make no sense at all to use a dynamically allocated array. There are no advantages, but there is the risk or running into resource leaks.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the objects in the vector without creating them. Your code should be like this:

```
for ( x = 0; x < size; x++)
{
    BoxOfProduce obj; //create an object
    obj.setItemAry();
    obj.randomPick();
    //.. set other properties
    box.push_back(obj); //insert it into the vector
}
```

`vector<BoxOfProduce>box;` will just create a vector, but it does not contain any `BoxOfProduce` object. So when you try to access the objects, program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your object and place them into the vector:

```
vector<BoxOfProduce> boxes;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    BoxOfProduce box;

    box.setItemAry();
    box.randomPick();

    box.display();
    box.change();
    box.display2();

    boxes.push_back(box); // Put a box into your vector 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this,

```
vector<BoxOfProduce>box;
cout<<"How many boxes you want";
cin>>size;
for ( x = 0; x < size; x++)
{
    BoxOfProduce obj; //create an object
    box.push_back(obj); //insert it into the vector
}

for ( x = 0; x < size; x++)
{
    box[x].setItemAry();
    box[x].randomPick();


    box[x].display();
    box[x].change();
    box[x].display2();
}
```

Comment: kk so yours works and all but now my when i cout enter type of vegi in my program, it comes up twice.

Comment: never mind i got thnx anyway it was just a cin.ignore() problem